# Next.JS How to get latest post from mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, next.js

I am building comment app. Problem I am facing is latest post/comment is on bottom. I would like to add new comment to first position.
Can you please tell me how to do it? Thank you.

```
import db from "@/utils/db";
import Comment from "@/models/Comment";

const handler = async (req, res) => {

  await db.connect()

  if (req.method !== 'GET') {
    return 
  }
  
  const comments = await Comment.find({})

  if(!comments) {
    return res.status(200).json({
      message: 'Comment section is EMPTY!'
    })
  }

res.status(200).send({ comments })
}

export default handler
```

my mongodb database is looking like this:

```
_id: 646be098d2de11097a4b62d6
user: 646bc68e673a78c472646e5e
userName:"john"
comment:"ffffffffffffffff"
like:0
createdAt:2023-05-22T21:37:28.018+00:00
updatedAt:2023-05-22T21:37:28.018+00:00
```

Answer (score 1):

To add new comments to the first position, you need to modify your code to `sort` the comments in descending order based on the creation date (`createdAt`) before sending the response.

```
 import db from "@/utils/db";
    import Comment from "@/models/Comment";
    
    const handler = async (req, res) => {
      await db.connect();
    
      if (req.method !== 'GET') {
        return;
      }
    
      const comments = await Comment.find({}).sort({ createdAt: -1 });
    
      if (!comments || comments.length === 0) {
        return res.status(200).json({
          message: 'Comment section is EMPTY!'
        });
      }
    
      res.status(200).send({ comments });
    };
    
    export default handler;
```

The `sort()` method is used on the `Comment.find({})` query to sort the comments based on the `createdAt` field in descending order (`-1` indicates descending order). This ensures that the latest comments will appear at the beginning of the `comments` array.